# Discriminated unions in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, f#, nhibernate-mapping

I'm wondering if there's any relatively easy way to extend NHibernate to support F#'s discriminated union. Not just a single IUserType or ICompositeUserType, but something generic that I can re-use regardless of the actual contents of the DU.

For example, suppose I have a property called RequestInfo, which is a union defined as:

```
type RequestInfo =  
    | Id of int
    | Name of string
```

This compiles into an abstract RequestInfo class, with concrete subclasses Id and Name. I can get all this info out just fine with F# reflection. In this case, I could store it in the database with "RequestInfo_Tag", "RequestInfo_Id", "RequestInfo_Name".

As I'm a NHibernate newbie, what kind of problems am I going to run into trying to follow this approach? Are more complex cases going to be impossible to deal with? For example, what about nested discriminated unions? Is there a way I can "hand off" the reading of the rest of the union to another ICompositeUserType?

More importantly, will this mess up my querying capabilities? Meaning, will I have to know the actual column names in the DB; I won't be able to do Criteria.Eq(SomeDiscUnion) and have it all sorted out?

I'm not looking for a complete "provide code" answer, just some general advice if this is even worth going after (and some pointers on how), or if I should just rethink my model.

Thanks!

P.S. Not to be rude, but if your answer consists of "use C#", it's not very helpful.

Comment: Very interesting question. I'm fairly fluent in both NHibernate and F#, I'll tackle this when I get some time

Comment: At least in my experience, I had hard time using NHibernate with F#, mostly because NHibernate requires objects to have a default constructor (which is frequently not the case for union types, record types, and most classes), and it relies on mutability to assign values to classes (which is frequently annoying to deal with in F# class definitions). More often than not, I get the database to play with F# by rolling my own mirco-ORM.

Comment: Yes, on our last project we just stuck to plain old object types so that they'd play nicely with NHibernate. This time I would like to branch out a little bit and try some more realistic models.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer to this, I think an F# API for NHibernate would be an awesome project to start on Codeplex :)

Comment: Yes, yes it would :). I don't mind sorting things out, I just don't know enough NHibernate to choose the right path.

Comment: I don't know nothing about F#, but if F# unions compiles to POCO (C# classes), this is in fact a NHibernate question which more people should be able to answer. Plese ignore me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Miguel, yes it compiles down to POCOs, with an inheritance hierarchy (each case is a subclass). So, yes, it's mainly NHibernate. But, I want to make sure we keep the F# feel to everything.

Comment: Would be very interested to hear if you got anywhere with this. Trying to do the same thing myself!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not been brave enough to try using NHibernate with F#'s type system, but it might help to look from the perspective of what's actually generated by the F# compiler.

If you look at your Discriminated Union in reflector, there are actually three classes generated (and more if you count the private debug proxies).

```
public abstract class RequestInfo : IStructuralEquatable, IComparable, IStructuralComparable
```

The first class, RequestInfo, is abstract, and is actually implemented by the other types in the union.

```
 // Nested Types
    [Serializable, DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Program.RequestInfo._Id@DebugTypeProxy)), DebuggerDisplay("{__DebugDisplay()}")]
    public class _Id : Program.RequestInfo
    {
        // Fields
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public readonly int id1;

        // Methods
        [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public _Id(int id1);
    }
    [Serializable, DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Program.RequestInfo._Name@DebugTypeProxy)), DebuggerDisplay("{__DebugDisplay()}")]
    public class _Name : Program.RequestInfo
    {
        // Fields
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public readonly string name1;

        // Methods
        [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public _Name(string name1);
    }
```

so when you do:

```
 let r=Id(5)
 let s=Name("bob")
```

r and s are instances of _Id and _Name, respectively.

So the answer to your question is likely the answer to one of the following questions:

- How do I map to an abstract class in nhibernate?
- How can I make NHibernate use a factory method?
- How can I create map Nhibernate to immutable objects?
- How do I do implement a custom type in NHibernate (presumably with IUserType).

Unfortunately, I'm not savvy enough to give you a coherent answer to any of those, but I'm sure someone else here has done at least one of these three solutions.

I'd like to think that you can use the same methods used for Inheritance Strategies, using, for example, a discriminator column, but I'm afraid the lack of a default constructor makes this problematic. So I'm inclined to think that using a custom type is the solution.

After some fiddling, here's a (possibly buggy and or broken) custom user type:

```
type RequestInfo =  
    | Id of int
    | Name of string

type RequestInfoUserType() as self =
    interface IUserType with
        member x.IsMutable = false
        member x.ReturnedType = typeof<RequestInfo>
        member x.SqlTypes = [| NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType(Data.DbType.String); NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType(Data.DbType.Int32); NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType(Data.DbType.String) |]
        member x.DeepCopy(obj) = obj //Immutable objects shouldn't need a deep copy
        member x.Replace(original,target,owner) = target // this might be ok
        member x.Assemble(cached, owner) = (x :> IUserType).DeepCopy(cached)
        member x.Disassemble(value) = (x :> IUserType).DeepCopy(value)

        member x.NullSafeGet(rs, names, owner)=
            // we'll use a column as a type discriminator, and assume the first mapped column is an int, and the second is a string.
            let t,id,name = rs.GetString(0),rs.GetInt32(1),rs.GetString(2) 
            match t with
                | "I" -> Id(id) :> System.Object
                | "N" -> Name(name) :> System.Object
                | _ -> null
        member x.NullSafeSet(cmd, value, index)=
            match value with
                | :? RequestInfo ->
                    let record = value :?> RequestInfo
                    match record with
                        | Id(i) ->
                            cmd.Parameters.Item(0) <- "I"
                            cmd.Parameters.Item(1) <- i
                        | Name(n) ->
                            cmd.Parameters.Item(0) <- "N"
                            cmd.Parameters.Item(2) <- n
                | _ -> raise (new  ArgumentException("Unexpected type"))

        member x.GetHashCode(obj) = obj.GetHashCode()
        member x.Equals(a,b) = 
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a,b)) then
                true
            else
                if (a=null && b=null) then
                    false
                else
                    a.Equals(b)
    end
```

This code could surely be made more generic, and should probably not be in your actual domain layer, but I thought it would be useful to take a stab at a F# implementation of IUserType.

Your mapping file would then do something like:

```
<property name="IdOrName" type="MyNamespace.RequestInfoUserType, MyAssembly"  >
  <column name="Type"/>
  <column name="Id"/>
  <column name="Name"/>
</property>
```

You probably can get away without a column for "Type" with a slight tweak to the custom UserType code.

I don't know how these custom user types work with queries/ICriteria, as I haven't really worked with custom user types much before.

Comment: Yep, mapping a single instance should be relatively easy. But what about when a DU contains another DU or something? I think I need some advanced composite user type that's recursive for this sort of thing to fully map properly in all cases. I'm also concerned about how this shows up for doing criteria.

Comment: Not sure how I'd handle that, either, but I suspect you could use a deeper pattern matching construct similar to my example above.